# Fixed points in the font with serifs

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Consider the English alphabet in this font with serifs

> **A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z**

Consider any letter in this font as a topological space (assume that letters don't have weight and are genersted by lines) and consider a continuous mapping from any letter to itself. For which letters any such mapping have a fixed point and for which it has not? For **O** the answer is negative, for **C**, **Z**, **S** it is positive.

The main difficulty for me is serifs. For the sans-serif font like **Arial** the problem is much easier. Here we can't even easily divide letters into topologically equal groups and these groups aren't obvious: **G** ~ **J**, **T** ~ **I** ~ **U** ~ **W**, **E** ~ **F**, **C** ~ **Z** ~ **S** etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of the letters deformation retracts to either a point, a circle, or a figure 8.

- If a letter deformation retracts to a point, Lefschetz fixed point theorem tells us that every map to itself has a fixed point.
- If a letter retracts to a circle, then the composition of the retraction with a rotation gives us a map which does not have a fixed point.
- If a letter retracts to a figure 8, the composition of the retraction with the map that collapses one of the loops to a point and rotates the other some angle does not have any fixed points.

In particular, the serifs play no role here.

Comment: If the letters do not have a weight, the figure 8 will be rather an 8 of a digital clock —this does not change anything, though.

Comment: But compactness + contractibility doesn't imply the fixed point property. Why here it implies?

Comment: I might say "the conjugation of a rotation of the circle by the retraction" instead of "the composition of the retraction with a rotation", since we're looking for a map from the letter-space to itself rather than from the letter-space to the circle.

Comment: There is a famous example due to Kinoshita of a compact, contractible space without the topological fixed point property: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm40/fm4019.pdf

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, I am not familiar with the example (I'll look later) but the Lefschetz fixed point theorem applies to compact triangulable spaces. If $X$ is such a space which is contractible and $f:X\to X$ is continuous, then the Lefschetz number of $f$ is $1$. (And the letters are obviously triangulable! :) )

Comment: @GregMartin, if you prefer, the composition of the retraction, a rotation of the circle and the inclusion of the circle in the big space :) (but not *conjugation*, as an interesting retraction rarely has an inverse)

Comment: @Nimza, see my comment above to Michael.

Comment: Thank you, @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez. And how to show that "If X is such a space which is contractible and f:X→X is continuous, then the Lefschetz number of f is 1"?

Comment: @Nimza: Since all the higher homology groups are zero, the Lefschetz number is simply the trace of the map induced on $H_0$. You can easily compute that!